# React Native iOS build release: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm using react native 0.62.3 and everything worked ok yesterday.

- After installing react-native-stripe-terminal package, I reverted everything, remove node_modules, Pods folders, reinstall and built to my iOS device with release scheme.
- The app is installed but it crashed on the launch screen before Metro Bundle is loaded.
- I tried to checkout the previous stable commit but same error.
- I tried to build with release scheme in 3 mac devices but same error (debug mode is not happed anything).

Can anyone help me to know what happens with my project or have the same error or which package causes the issue? Thank you!

Here is my packages list:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@dooboo-ui/native-switch-toggle": "^0.3.3",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
        "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.2",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.1.0",
        "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
        "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.0.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.4.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.7.3",
        "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.4.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.4.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.4.0",
        "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.2.1",
        "appcenter": "4.0.0",
        "appcenter-analytics": "4.0.0",
        "appcenter-crashes": "4.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "base-64": "^0.1.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "card-validator": "^6.2.0",
        "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
        "emoji-datasource": "^6.0.0",
        "engine.io-client": "3.4.4",
        "html-entities": "^1.3.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "lodash.compact": "^3.0.1",
        "lodash.every": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.pick": "^4.4.0",
        "lodash.values": "^4.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "16.11.0",
        "react-native": "0.62.3",
        "react-native-autoheight-webview": "^1.5.8",
        "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.0",
        "react-native-big-calendar": "^0.1.32",
        "react-native-calendar-picker": "^6.1.2",
        "react-native-calendars": "^1.260.0",
        "react-native-camera": "^4.0.0",
        "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.5",
        "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4",
        "react-native-device-info": "^8.1.3",
        "react-native-document-picker": "^4.1.0",
        "react-native-elements": "^1.2.1",
        "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
        "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.0.0",
        "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
        "react-native-fs": "2.15.2",
        "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.3",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
        "react-native-gps-state": "^2.0.3",
        "react-native-highlight-words": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
        "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.3",
        "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-intercom": "13.2.0",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
        "react-native-media-controls": "^2.2.0",
        "react-native-mixpanel": "^1.2.5",
        "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
        "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.2",
        "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.3.1",
        "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.1",
        "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.9",
        "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-push-notification": "^7.4.0",
        "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
        "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.0.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.2",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
        "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.10",
        "react-native-signature-pad": "^0.1.0",
        "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-square-in-app-payments": "^1.5.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
        "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.2",
        "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.1.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
        "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
        "react-native-view-overflow": "0.0.4",
        "react-native-webview": "11.4.4",
        "react-navigation": "^3.12.1",
        "react-navigation-animated-switch": "^0.4.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
        "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "socket.io-client": "2.4.0",
        "tipsi-stripe": "^7.5.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.6.2",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.6.2",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
        "eslint": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
        "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
        "prettier": "^2.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "setupFiles": [
            "./path/to/jestSetupFile.js"
        ]
    }
```

Xcode console show this

```
objc[35818]: Class MGLFaux3DUserLocationAnnotationView is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox (0x109927f90) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/MyApp (0x103aa7068). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35818]: Class MGLUserLocationHeadingArrowLayer is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox (0x109928620) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/MyApp (0x103aa71a8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35818]: Class MGLUserLocationHeadingBeamLayer is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox (0x109929520) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/MyApp (0x103aa71f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2021-12-17 14:08:04.728837+0700 MyApp[35818:1435990] 8.0.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more.
2021-12-17 14:08:04.729565+0700 MyApp[35818:1435808] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 8.0.0
2021-12-17 14:08:04.913803+0700 MyApp[35818:1435808] [AppCenterCrashes] WARNING: -[MSACCrashes configureCrashReporterWithUncaughtExceptionHandlerEnabled:]/731 Detecting crashes is NOT enabled due to running the app with a debugger attached.
2021-12-17 14:08:04.933688+0700 MyApp[35818:1435808] 
[CodePush] Loading JS bundle from file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F15A17B-0A62-4055-80B0-24F845FC70CC/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle
2021-12-17 14:08:05.148221+0700 MyApp[35818:1436001] 8.0.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
firebase/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2021-12-17 14:08:05.149318+0700 MyApp[35818:1436001] 8.0.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '126625914542'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
2021-12-17 14:08:05.175 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
2021-12-17 14:08:05.178 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2021-12-17 14:08:05.188 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
2021-12-17 14:08:05.189107+0700 MyApp[35818:1435997] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded., stack:
<unknown>@(null):(null)
v@2:1267
<unknown>@454.js:1:101
v@2:1473
<unknown>@453.js:1:127
v@2:1473
<unknown>@439.js:1:140
v@2:1473
<unknown>@405.js:1:650
v@2:1473
<unknown>@1.js:1:57
v@2:1473
d@2:875
global code@7:3
'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181cf5c9c 0x198ea9758 0x102f365ec 0x102fb0bd0 0x102fb14f8 0x181c848d0 0x181ca05a8 0x181cd480c 0x102f650d4 0x102f67280 0x102f66ff0 0x1050e0718 0x1050e1f94 0x1050e9150 0x1050e9dd4 0x1050f54e8 0x1dbcc1e84 0x1dbcc19f0)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded., stack:
<unknown>@(null):(null)
v@2:1267
<unknown>@454.js:1:101
v@2:1473
<unknown>@453.js:1:127
v@2:1473
<unknown>@439.js:1:140
v@2:1473
<unknown>@405.js:1:650
v@2:1473
<unknown>@1.js:1:57
v@2:1473
d@2:875
global code@7:3
'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvh5t.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have started to get this issue right after installing "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and I see thet you have this packeg also

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33137489)

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee that this will solve your problem, but it might help.

Because you deleted everything, you may need to reinstall your packages.

To do that, try the following:

in your terminal, in the root of your project, run
`npm i` or `yarn`. Then

`cd ios`

`pod install`.

Then open the xcworkspace in XCode and press Command-Shift-K to do a full clean.

You can then run your iOS build task again and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @José Mancharo, I have done full clean and built .xcworkspace but it still happened. I can't release the app because of this :( I see the xcode console highlight the dispatch_async of the react native lib, at the initBridge step but I can debug what cause this problem 

Comment: You could always try reverting a few more commits back until it works, then adding each part back manually until it fails, then you'll know what causes the issue. If you are sure it isn't your machine or your cache, it must be your code. Does it build Android OK?

Comment: Android is working normally, only iOS has the problem

Comment: Hi @José Mancharo, it takes me over 2 weeks to find out what caused the problem   Our project is too big and it contain a js file with more than 1000 export constants. It takes the command line tools or similar broken. We have 1 week to split the js to smaller file and it builds successfully! Thanks for your answers.